# Javascript Object via AJAX to PHP Array

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, object

I am trying to send following javascript object using AJAX

```
var bodycontent = {
  search: search,
  query: query,
  start: start,
  show: show,
};
```

My AJAX call

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: dataString,
    cache: false,
    url: 'url.php',
    success: function(html) {
        alert(html);
    }
})
```

The variable dataString

```
var dataString = "bodycontent="+bodycontent;
```

I tried console.log for bodycontent to ensure it had data and the result is as follows

```
{search: "human", query: Array(1), start: 20, show: 40}
```

On PHP page I tried follow code to decode the object being sent

```
json_decode($_POST['bodycontent'],true)
```

But the value is empty. If I don't json_decode it returns [object Object]

Comment: have you looked at `JSON.stringify` to convert that Object literal to a string?

Comment: Try converting your object to string with `data: JSON.stringify([dataString ])`

Comment: I have tried converting it to JSON.stringify but same result.. print_r(json_decode($_POST['bodycontent'],true) returns an empty alert

Comment: [jQuery ajax](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-url-settings) expects `data` to be a live object, a string or an array. You're posting this string: "bodycontent=[object Object]", and that's not valid JSON, which your server expects to get.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't concatenate an object and a string

Just send the object as `data` and jQuery will serialize it internally

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: bodycontent ,
    cache: false,// pointless since POST doesn't get cached by browser
    url: 'url.php',
    success: function(html) {
        alert(html);
    }
})
```

Then in php look for the individual keys within your object like:

```
$_POST['search']  
$_POST['query']// will be array since that's what you are sending
etc
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use `JSON.stringify` you can prepare the object for transmission by casting as a string. The payload of the ajax request takes the name `bodycontent` as the parameter ( and you will look for that in the POSTed data ) and appends the stringified object literal data.

```
<?php
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' ){
        ob_clean();
        $body=json_decode($_POST['bodycontent']);
        exit( print_r( $body, true ) );
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title></title>
        <script src='//code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js'></script>
        <script>
            // whatever this should be...
            var bodycontent = {
                search: 'human',
                query: [1,2,3,4,5,6],
                start: 20,
                show: 40
            };
            
            
            $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                data:{ bodycontent:JSON.stringify( bodycontent ) },
                cache:false,
                url:'url.php',
                success:function(html) {
                    alert(html);
                }
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- content -->
    </body>
</html>
```